# Filegroups for a database in Restoring mode

Tags: sql-server

I need to get the name column `sys.filegroups` with the help of the data-space_id.
Since the database I want to query for is in restoring mode, I cannot make use of sys.filegroups.
Is there any other way of finding the name of the filegroups without changing the mode?

Is there a one to one mapping between data_space_id and filegorups name, like 1 --> PRIMARY

That'd be helpful to skip sys.filegroups to pull the name and simply use such a mapping

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [RESTORE FILELISTONLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY   
FROM DISK = 'PathToYourBackupFile.bak';
```

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-sets) says:

> A client can use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to obtain a list of the files
> contained in a backup set. This information is returned as a result
> set containing one row for each file.

One of the columns returned is `FileGroupName`. It shows the name of the filegroup that contains the file.

Comment: Cannot use the backupfile.

Comment: @SonaliGupta isn't the database in restore mode because of a backup being restored? And there's no backup at all for that database? You could use an older backup file just to find the name you need.

Comment: The backup restoring is not in my hand, so the backup file may or may not be on the system that I can access. If I use an old backup, isn't it a probability that the filegroups might have been changed?

Comment: @SonaliGupta, yes, it's possible that the filegroups have changed, but filegroups aren't changed that much so if you have a backup of last week, chances are good the database schema is all the same. Could you share what's the purpose of you finding the filegroups in this situation of a database stuck in restore mode?